# Why do I get this validation error? "start tag in table body"

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to validate my html but I keep getting this message:
*Error: td start tag in table body.
From line 38, column 6; to line 39, column 4
/td>↩↩↩<p st*

I would be thankful for any recommendations as I'm stuck.

```
<div class="container">
<table style="margin:0 auto; background-color: #ffe1d8;">
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><h2 style="text-align:center">Tävlingsresultat</h2></td>
</tr>
<td>
```

Comment: Error is not on this peace of code. See that your error contains code `</td><p st...>` - look for it.

Comment: is this the complete code that you have posted? Do you have a closing </table> tag in the actual code?

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking totally at the wrong place, I blame it on lack of coffee.

Comment: Feel free to delete

Answer (score 0):

Look at the last line.

You have a `<td>` (a start tag for a td element) which is a child of the (implit) tbody element.

A td element **must** be a child of a tr element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
   <table style="margin:0 auto; background-color: #ffe1d8;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><h2 style="text-align:center">Tävlingsresultat</h2></td>
        </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

you have a `<td>` in the last row. A `<td>` tag is always child of `<tr>` tag